# Solidity Undeclared identifier. s not (or not yet) visible at this point. but it is

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I'm making if else function and if price == stopOrder it should do executeOrder but it's giving me error

```
    function sellLogic() public {
        require(StopOrder != 0 || LimitOrder != 0, "stop order or LimitOrder are 0!");

       
        //if else to se if it will sell during the dump
       
        if (price >= LimitOrder){
            sell = true;
            

        }
        else if (price == StopOrder){
            executeOrder;
            
        }
        else {
            sell = false;
        }
}

 function executeOrder(uint orderId) external returns (uint[] memory) {
            sellLogic(); 

            Order memory order = orderBook[orderId];  
            require(sell == true, "Price is lower than your limit order,or stop order didnt got reached");
            require(order.traderAddress != address(0), "Invalid order");
            require(order.orderState == OrderState.Created, 'Invalid order state');
        
            updateOrder(order, OrderState.Finished);
    
            address[] memory pair = new address[](2);
            pair[0] = order.assetIn;
            pair[1] = order.assetOut;

            uint[] memory swapResult;
        
            if (order.orderType == OrderType.EthForTokens) {
                swapResult = uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokens{value:order.assetInOffered}(order.assetOutExpected, pair, order.traderAddress, block.timestamp);
                TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(stakeAddress, order.stake.mul(STAKE_PERCENTAGE).div(100));
                TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(owAddress, order.stake.mul(100-STAKE_PERCENTAGE).div(100));
                    
            } 
            else if (order.orderType == OrderType.TokensForEth) {
                TransferHelper.safeApprove(order.assetIn, address(uniswapV2Router), order.assetInOffered);
                swapResult = uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETH(order.assetInOffered, order.assetOutExpected, pair, order.traderAddress, block.timestamp);
                }
            
            else if (order.orderType == OrderType.TokensForTokens) {
                TransferHelper.safeApprove(order.assetIn, address(uniswapV2Router), order.assetInOffered);
                swapResult = uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokens(order.assetInOffered, order.assetOutExpected, pair, order.traderAddress, block.timestamp);
                }
        
            TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(msg.sender, order.executorFee);
            emit logOrderExecuted(order.id, msg.sender, swapResult);
        
            return swapResult;
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Probably you are missing a `}` before `function executeOrder.`

Comment: no its not all code thats good

Comment: This line in `executeOrder;` doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to do? To call that function you need to pass the orderId parameter.

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: If you have the orderId then just with `executeOrder(orderId)` you will call it. If you don't have `orderId` the you should require the user to pass it as parameter to sellLogic.

Comment: still geting error Undeclared identifier. "executeOrder" is not (or not yet) visible at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121082/discussion-between-toni-dev-and-ismael).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future viewers, just in case someone stumbles across this while learning and gets confused:

Calling `this.executeOrder()` in this way, requires a costly EVM message call, where you probably want an internal call. In this case, two changes to the above code improve things:

1. Change the executeOrder call to `executeOrder(orderId)`, after making `orderId` available to the call site, and
2. Change the *declaration* of the `executeOrder` function to be `public` instead of `external`.

After (2), the `executeOrder` declaration should be:

```
function executeOrder(uint orderId) public returns (uint[] memory) {
    [...]
}
```

See [the Solidity docs on visibility](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) for details.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is made by @Ismael

```
this.executeOrder(orderId);
```